# JPA1 - ID is part of superclass results into error because of missing @Id in @Entity annotated class

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, eclipselink, toplink

we are currently evaluating JPA for our persistence unit and we got a problem when the id is part of the superclass. We always get the error message that the @Id must be in the same class as the @Entitiy annotation.

```
public abstract class DomainBean {

@Id
private long id;

}

@Entity
public class property extends DomainBean {}
```

We could archive this problem when we use a XML mapping file. Is there any known resolution by using annotations?

Due to the problem that we must use WebLogic 10.3.1 we are limited to JPA1 and EclipseLink/TopLink but we can't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DomainBean` must be annotated with [`@MappedSuperclass`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) for its JPA annotations to take effect.